# how to make screencast using my computer

Tags: video

many developer make video that in video "they show they write something on  their PC". i found that behind the video the voice i hear of developer and video they take using software in computer not by camera.

Which software they used to make the screencast. Are their any way or minimum requirement to make the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TechSmith's Camtasia is pretty good at this for a free version:
http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/

It uses the built in microphone to record your voice as you record screen activity.

However, there are plenty of other great paid-for alternatives for recording screen activity along with voice. Just Google away...

Comment: i feel bad about both's sound quality [camtasia and jing]

Answer (score 0):

google and wikipedia - your friends

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software

Answer (score 0):

[Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/) is a good shareware multiplatform screencaster. It has a limitation as to what type of video output is available, and a 5 minute video limit on the non-paid version. Very good once paid for. And the limits on the free version don't matter much while you learn to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) before and it's free (open source).

From the web site:

> CamStudio is able to record all screen
>   and audio activity on your computer
>   and create industry-standard AVI video
>   files and using its built-in SWF
>   Producer can turn those AVIs into
>   lean, mean, bandwidth-friendly
>   Streaming Flash videos (SWFs)